# The 'class object' prints its name using `.__name__`,despite of the absence of `__name__` attribute

Tags: python

Class_object's name is accessible  through `.__name__`,
See the codes:

```
>>> object
<class 'object'>
>>> object.__name__
'object'
```

Nevertheless, the `__name__` method  `is` `not` `in` class_object's default setting.

the codes:

```
>>> foo = dir(object)
>>> foo
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> foo.count('__name__')
0    # '__name__' is not in list
```

object is a base for all classes. It has the methods that are common to all instances of Python classes.

Where `__name__`'s setting is located in?

Comment: I found this to be really interesting so I decided to try to figure out how this whole thing works.  I've posted an answer on the marked dupe for anyone who might be interested in digging a little deeper (and/or correcting my current understanding of how the CPython interpreter works)

Comment: `type` inherit form 'class object', `>>> type.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the class body is executed Python will fill in some attributes automatically. That includes `__name__` but also `__doc__`, `__qualname__` (Python 3.4+) and `__module__`. The complete list of these automated attributes is avaiable as [table in the `inspect` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#types-and-members):

```
Type    Attribute       Description
class   __doc__         documentation string
        __name__        name with which this class was defined
        __qualname__    qualified name
        __module__      name of module in which this class was defined
```

These are defined by the base metaclass of Python classes: `type` (see also [@Szabolcs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634058/5393381)).

```
>>> '__name__' in dir(object.__class__)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `object` is constructed with `type` so you can find `__name__` in `dir(type)`:

```
>>> '__name__' in dir(type)
True
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: the inheritances are also show with `dir`. I though so too initially.

Comment: ... but `type.__name__` results in `'type'`, not `'object'`  -- is it a descriptor?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis -- Also, careful here.  `object` doesn't inherit from `type` -- `object`'s `type` (i.e. metaclass) is `type`.

Comment: Yes,`type` inherits from `class object`,`>>> type.__bases__ (<class 'object'>,) `this is the paradox about attribute `__name__`'s absence.@mgilson